# Using Masterpages inhibits VSDoc help integration in VS2010

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, vsdoc

I am currently working on a MVC3 project in C# and VS2010 using a lot of jQuery.

I always wondered why I could not display the VsDoc help files although they are included in the right place and version.

I just found out that the VsDoc help does really only work if you include jQuery in the same page you are working on.

Of course I have put my include files into the masterpage of the project, so I do not have to modify each and every view if I change anything.

Did anyone find a solution to using VsDoc for jQuery and NOT having to include jQuery in each view?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to include jQuery in each view - [you can just reference the vdocs themselves](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNETAJAX/183_Using_JQuery_in_ASPNet_AJAX_Applications_%E2%80%93_Part_1.aspx).

However, another (better) solution would be to not include your jQuery and JavaScript code directly in your views. Separate them out into their own JavaScript (*.js) files. There are many reasons why you would want to do this and this would also solve your problem.